# How to group by and select (to create increment) in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
foreach (var item in orderedItems.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }) 
{
  item.x.Index = item.i + 1;
  //some stuff here
}
```

It allows me to set index of an item.
Now i need to group items by some parameter(item.Date) and create indexes for items only inside the group.Like this: {group1:1,2,3}{group2:1,2}

When i try smth like:

```
foreach (var taskGr in orderedItems.GroupBy(x=>x.TaskDate).Select((x, i) => new { x, i }));
{
  foreach (var task in taskGr)
  {
    //task.Index =...           
  }
}
```

I got

> "Type
>   '{x:System.Linq.IGrouping,Models.Task>,
>   i:int}' is not enumerable"

on taskGr

Is there any way to do it via LINQ query?

Comment: Don´t use linq to *update* values, as it is designed for *queyring* them. Use a normal loop and update the values of the elements from your query.

Comment: There is not enough information here, please show your data structure, and you intended output specifically. this is hard to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will depend on your requirements. Assuming you only need the indices per group, but not an grouped enumerable itself (and the items are relatively cheap to create), you can do the following

```
var itemsWithIndexPerGroup = orderedItems.GroupBy(item => item.Group)
                                         .Select(group => group.Select((item, index) => new Item(item) { Index = index }))
                                         .SelectMany(item => item);
```

*Explanation:* You are first grouping the `IEnumerable` by `Item.Group`, which essentially yields an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable`s. We are then selecting each of the `IEnumerable`s and project its items to new items bearing the index. The will still yield an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Item>>`, hence we are then using `SelectMany` to return a flat `IEnumerable<Item>` of all the items from the nested `IEnumerables`.

If you need a grouped `IEnumerable` with the group key, you can still group this wil `GroupBy` at the end. If you need grouped `IEnumerables, but don't need the group key, you can simply omit the`SelectMany`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! That helps me to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar

```
var orderedItems = Enumerable.Range(1,15)
                   .Select(x=> new Order{Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(x%3)});
    var indexItems = orderedItems.GroupBy(x=>x.Date)
                   .SelectMany(x=>x.ToList()
                            .Select((c,index)=>new Order{Date= x.Key, Index=index+1}));
```

Where Order is defined as

```
public class Order
{
    public int Index{get;set;}
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
}
```

This would give an output as

```
Index Date
1 18-01-2019 15:59:47 
2 18-01-2019 15:59:47 
3 18-01-2019 15:59:47 
4 18-01-2019 15:59:47 
1 19-01-2019 15:59:47 
2 19-01-2019 15:59:47 
3 19-01-2019 15:59:47 
1 17-01-2019 15:59:47 
2 17-01-2019 15:59:47 
3 17-01-2019 15:59:47
```